# How do you access the verbose output from a Github Actions Azure functions deployment?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I am currently trying to deploy a Python Azure Function to a Function App using Github Actions.

The deployment code is as follows:-

```
name: Deploy Azure Function Dev
env:
    PYTHON_VERSION: "3.7"
    WORKING_DIR: ${{ github.workspace }}/data-science-data-acquisition
    FUNCTION_APP_DEV: "data-science-data-acquisition"

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    types: [opened,reopened,edited]
    paths: 
      - 'data-science-data-acquisition/**'
  push:
    branches: [master]
    paths: 
      - 'data-science-data-acquisition/**'
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: "Checkout"
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Run pip'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # If your function app project is not located in your repository's root
        # Please change your directory for pip in pushd
        pushd ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }}
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
        popd

    - name: 'Azure Login'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS_DEV }}

    - name: 'Deploy Function App'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.FUNCTION_APP_DEV }}
        package: ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }}
```

We are currently having an issue with the deployment, however the output within Github Actions is pretty limited:-

```
##[PublishContent]
Waiting for function app to spin up after app settings change.
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history.
Bad Request (CODE: 400)
##[error]Execution Exception (state: PublishContent) (step: Invocation)
##[error]  When request Azure resource at PublishContent, zipDeploy : Failed to use /home/runner/work/_temp/temp_web_package_6376243339903418.zip as ZipDeploy content
##[error]    Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Conflict (CODE: 409)
##[error]      Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Conflict (CODE: 409)
    at Kudu.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/azure-actions-appservice-rest/Kudu/azure-app-kudu-service.js:155:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/azure-actions-appservice-rest/Kudu/azure-app-kudu-service.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
##[error]Deployment Failed!
##[error]Node run failed with exit code 1
```

When deploying directly from VSCode, there is far more verbose output which is obviously quite useful for troubleshooting a deployment: is there a way to enable/access this from the Github Actions deployment?

I've checked the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/functions-action) for Azure/functions-action and the Python specific example but can't see anything to enable this.

Comment: Hm, maybe you can find any useful information in the Kudu logs? Also, to solve your deployment error, did you try to stop the web app before you deploy?

Comment: Hi Martin; I'm fairly new at deploying function apps - where are the Kudu logs accessed from, and would there be a way to output them to the github actions log as an artifact or similar?  This would be useful as there will be developers making changes to the function who may not have direct access to the function app etc especially when deployed to prod.

For the deployment error itself, pretty sure it's a problem with the size of the zip package being created; but happy to cross that bridge once we have full access to the logs etc.

Comment: Hi Matthew, check out this post: [Get Azure App Service deployment logs from KUDU
](https://benperk.github.io/msdn/2014/2014-04-get-azure-website-deployment-logs-from-kudu.html)

Comment: Thanks will check it out.  In terms of the function app itself - it actually deploys fine to our staging environment as well, so not really sure what's goosed in the dev env!

Comment: Destroyed the function app completely; recreated, and it still broke, so created a new storage account for this, and now it works.  So, I'm assuming there's some issue with the storage account being used.  I'll try and have a look at how to get the logging from Kudu up into the github action output a bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out the verbose output *was* being displayed however, only on the first run of the action; when it was re-run a different error was causing an issue and so the expected output was masked, and overwritten on the re-run.